# Ethercard. Copying ip address into hisip

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet

I've tried getting help from arduino.cc forum but they arent helping at all (more like being cryptic) i'm kinda a newb at this. And i'm seriously not getting help from there. 2 messages in 8 days from one person and they arent helping.

i have a project that does following

-connects to network
-Gets ip address
-finds UDP broadcaster
-Connections to a web server's hard coded ip address and grabs data
-displays it on a screen.

that works fine. but i been trying to get the UDP broadcaster's ip address into the http part of the code so it connects to the broadcaster without having to hard code the IP Address.

here is my code. i want to have the ip address thats is grabed by the udpSerialPrint stament and have it put into the ether.hisip and use it in the ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/arduino"), "", website, my_callback);

Hope you can help. Thank you.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include "NexText.h"
#include "NexPage.h"
#include <IPAddress.h>

// Present a "Will be back soon web page", as stand-in webserver.
// 2011-01-30 <jc@wippler.nl> http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

#define STATIC 0  // set to 1 to disable DHCP (adjust myip/gwip values below)

// ethernet mac address - must be unique on your network
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer;

const int buzzer = 9; //buzzer to arduino pin 9

String ipaddy;
String CurrentTime;
String MainBroadcastIP;
String MainBroadcastIP2;
String Solarwatts;
String BatteryA;
String BatterySOC;
String Housewatts;
String Systemname;
String Updatetime;
String BatteryV;

NexText txtstartup = NexText(0,1,"txtstartup");
NexText txtsystemname = NexText(0,2,"txtsystem");
NexText txtsolarw = NexText(0,3,"txtsolar");
NexText txtbatterya = NexText(0,4,"txtbatterya");
NexText txthousew = NexText(0,5,"txthousew");
NexText txtbatterySOC = NexText(0,6,"txtbatterySOC");
NexText txtupdatetime = NexText(0,7,"txtupdate");
NexPage PageMain1 = NexPage(0,8,"Main1");


const char website[] PROGMEM = "192.168.15.3";

NexTouch *nexListenList[] = 
{
    &txtstartup,
    &PageMain1,
    &txtsystemname,
    &txtsolarw,
    &txtbatterya,
    &txthousew,
    &txtbatterySOC,
    &txtupdatetime,
    &PageMain1,
    NULL
};



void setup(){
  dbSerial.begin(9600);
  nexInit();

  Serial.println("\n[AC-DC Power Monitor]");
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  txtstartup.setText("Welcome! System is Starting");
  delay(2000);
  txtstartup.setText("Attempting to Obtain an \r IP Address");
  delay(2000);

  Serial.println("Initialising the Ethernet controller");
  //Mega is ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 53)
  //Duo is ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 10)
    if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 53) == 0) {
        Serial.println("Ethernet controller NOT initialised");
        txtstartup.setText("Network Card not detected!");
        while (true);
    }

    Serial.println("Attempting to get an IP address using DHCP");
    if (ether.dhcpSetup()) {
        ether.udpServerListenOnPort(&udpSerialPrint, 8888);
        ether.printIp("Got an IP address using DHCP: ", ether.myip);
        char a1[10],a2[10],a3[10],a4[10];
        sprintf(a1,"%d",ether.myip[0]);
        sprintf(a2,"%d",ether.myip[1]);
        sprintf(a3,"%d",ether.myip[2]);
        sprintf(a4,"%d",ether.myip[3]);
        ipaddy = String(a1) + "." + a2 + "." + a3 + "." + a4;
        String msgtext = "Got IP: " + ipaddy;
        txtstartup.setText(msgtext.c_str());
        tone(buzzer, 1000); // Send 1KHz sound signal...
        delay(250);        // ...for 1 sec
        noTone(buzzer);     // Stop sound...
        delay(250);        // ...for 1 sec
        tone(buzzer, 1000); // Send 1KHz sound signal...
        delay(250);        // ...for 1 sec
        noTone(buzzer);     // Stop sound...

    } else {
        tone(buzzer, 400); // Send 0.4KHz sound signal...
        delay(500);        // ...for 1 sec
        noTone(buzzer);     // Stop sound...
        delay(500);        // ...for 1 sec
        tone(buzzer, 400); // Send 0.4KHz sound signal...
        delay(500);        // ...for 1 sec
        noTone(buzzer);     // Stop sound.
        exit(0);      
    }

    #if 1
      // use DNS to resolve the website's IP address
      if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
        Serial.println("DNS failed");
    #elif 2
      // if website is a string containing an IP address instead of a domain name,
      // then use it directly. Note: the string can not be in PROGMEM.
      char websiteIP[] = "192.168.1.1";
      ether.parseIp(ether.hisip, websiteIP);
    #else
      // or provide a numeric IP address instead of a string
      byte hisip[] = { 192,168,1,1 };
      ether.copyIp(ether.hisip, hisip);
    #endif

    delay(2000);
    PageMain1.show();
    ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);
}

void loop(){
        ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 1000;
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("<<< REQ ");
    ether.hisport = 8181;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/arduino"), "", website, my_callback);
  }

}

void checkserver()
{
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println();


}

void udpSerialPrint(word port, byte ip[4], const char *data, word len) {
IPAddress src(ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
        char a1[10],a2[10],a3[10],a4[10];
        sprintf(a1,"%d",src[0]);
        sprintf(a2,"%d",src[1]);
        sprintf(a3,"%d",src[2]);
        sprintf(a4,"%d",src[3]);

        MainBroadcastIP = String(a1) + "." + a2 + "." + a3 + "." + a4;
      return;
}

String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
    int found = 0;
    int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
    int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
            found++;
            strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
            strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
        }
    }
    return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}



char* string2char(String command){
    if(command.length()!=0){
        char *p = const_cast<char*>(command.c_str());
        return p;
    }
}



static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  Serial.println(">>>");
  Ethernet::buffer[off+300] = 0;
  String web = (const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off;
  Serial.println((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off);
  int weblengh = web.length();
  String web2 = web.substring(131,weblengh);
  Serial.println("System Name: " + getValue(web2, ',', 0));
  Systemname = getValue(web2, ',', 0);
  Serial.println("Solar Watts: " + getValue(web2, ',', 1) + "W");
  Solarwatts = getValue(web2, ',', 1) + "W";
  Serial.println("House Watts: " + getValue(web2, ',', 2) + "W");
  Housewatts = getValue(web2, ',', 2) + "W";
  Serial.println("Battery SOC: " + getValue(web2, ',', 3) + "%");
  BatterySOC = getValue(web2, ',', 3) + "%";
  Serial.println("Battery Volts: " + getValue(web2, ',', 4) + "V");
  BatteryV = getValue(web2, ',', 4) + "V";
  Serial.println("Battery Amps: " + getValue(web2, ',', 5) + "A");
  BatteryA = getValue(web2, ',', 5) + "A";
  Serial.println("Battery Amps: " + getValue(web2, ',', 6));
  Serial.println("Battery Amps: " + getValue(web2, ',', 7));
  Serial.println("Time: " + getValue(web2, ',', 8));
  Updatetime = getValue(web2, ',', 8);

  txtsystemname.setText(Systemname.c_str());
  txtsolarw.setText(Solarwatts.c_str());
  txthousew.setText(Housewatts.c_str());
  txtbatterySOC.setText(BatterySOC.c_str());
  txtbatterya.setText(BatteryA.c_str());
  txtupdatetime.setText(Updatetime.c_str());

}
```

Comment: I would recommend isolating the issue and writing a small test sketch. It is very difficult for anybody to simply jump in and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `ether` is global, so you can access it from your `udpSerialPrint` function. That function gets passed the IP address in the `ip[4]` array, so you can just use `ether.copyIp(ether.hisip, ip);` to set it.

I would also set a flag to say "I have got the IP address" and only attempt to do anything with the website when you know the IP address has been given to you.

Comment: I dont know what i;m doing wrong. but i have tried adding ether.copyIp(ether.hisip, ip) to the udpSerialPrint  statement and it didnt work.

Comment: Scratch that. i got it to work now., Thank you very much